# Election candidate statistics overlap candidate's user card, plus sprite CSS problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, election, formatting

There is a display problem on [the current election page](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/4#post-341797).
Information overlaps the "user card" and hurts legibility.

Compare (bad):

[image: Bad CSS]

To better from [the current Philosophy election](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination#post-36875):

[image: Good CSS]

Note that this issue occurs on both Firefox and Chrome and has also [been reported by TylerH, Kit Z. Fox, and Dronz](https://english.stackexchange.com/election/4#post-341787) (Linked nomination now deleted. ¿10K can see?).

---

---

**Additional:**
Note the extra elements as pointed out by Marthaª, in the comments:

[image: Ugly CSs]

Are from [the same sprite set (`sprites-extra.svg`) as the "user card"](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/english/img/sprites-extra.svg?v=0d6e2bde6aea):

[image: EL&U extras, sprite set]

This indicates that the element, that contains the sprite, is not sized correctly.

Comment: Extra data point: I get the same bug under Safari (v9.1, on Mac OS 10.11.4).  I guess this suggests it’s not a particularly browser-specific issue.

Comment: If I could, I would give you another +1 for your beautiful hand-drawn circles (and emoticons).

Comment: I can't figure out what the two dingbats are supposed to go with: they're not centered over anything that I can tell. Also, there's a superfluous border to the left of the "reviews | meta posts" line.

Comment: also seen in Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m

Comment: @Marthaª, they are part of [the "extras" sprite set](http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/english/img/sprites-extra.svg?v=0d6e2bde6aea), and are not supposed to show there at all. The left border is also part of that same set. ... The height and width was not set correctly on that element.

Comment: Safari 9.0.2 also looks like first image.

Comment: It should be noted that this problem isn't limited to elections; we've had other issues where the user box wasn't sized properly. Sometimes the right kind of username will cause the box to stretch in ways it wasn't meant to. Probably the fix for this is to use an SVG element with content inside instead of a backgorund image, or to use border sprites, or sliding door sprites. This has been a problem for years.

Comment: I agree that it looks messy, and is maybe a little distracting, but I don't know if I'd go so far to say that it "hurts legibility" (I'm not looking at it on a phone, though).

Comment: I too wish I could give you an extra +1 for those magnificent and humorous faces.

Comment: @BrockAdams Frankly, I'd be disappointed if you did use Photoshop (though I do detect sarcasm). Such crude drawings should ALWAYS be done in Paint! :P

Comment: Wrong tags, Brock. Please tag it with [design]. I wonder if a dev would've come by if you did.

Comment: Firefox 38.8.0 / Debian Wheezy looks the same as the "bad" screenshot at the top.

Comment: chrome 52 / W7 has the same problem as the first image for *every candidate*

Comment: Someone from the design team is having a look at this in the next day or two.

Comment: Marking no longer reproducible.

Comment: Thanks, @MetaEd, but [status-completed] is more appropriate -- As this was a massively verified/reproduced bug, and the code has obviously been fixed/replaced in the last 2 years.

Comment: @BrockAdams I get what you are saying. I avoided [tag:status-completed] because I'm not on the development team and have no way to verify that the bug was fixed (as opposed to, say, occluded).

Comment: @MetaEd, I understand, but a great many bugs on SO, MetaSE, and Stack Apps are silently fixed with no feedback from a dev other than obviously changed code and behavior.  We've marked these as status-completed with no issues.